# Placing values for longitude and latitude into a map field via PodioKit API?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, podio

I automatically read out the location data from images and want to use this longitude and latitude and set them for the value of a location/map field using PodioKit.

I already tried Google maps URL like

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=53.550556,9.993333&ll=53.550556,9.993333&z=17
```

or

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview?q=53.550556,9.993333&ll=53.550556,9.993333&z=17
```

but had bad luck. I'm trying to use PodioKit and the documentation only talks about setting the "string value" of a location/map field. Possibly this question is too specific, but maybe another user found a solution or just a hint to push me into the right direction...

Cheers,
Michael / Hamburg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian at Podio here. Actually there is API support for submitting a latitude/longitude instead of a string but it is yet to be implemented in PodioKit. It should be very easy to add though, so I will have a look at it as soon as possible. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: That will be great! I'm looking forward to using it :-)

Comment: I have now added support for this, and you can use it by providing a `PKTLocation` as a value to your field, like `item[@"location-field"] = [[PKTLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:55.6646305 longitude:12.5657289];`

You need to run `pod update` to get the latest changes. Let me know if that solves the problem for you.

Comment: It works as described! Great, simple and fast solution!
Thanks a lot!